# Travis CI RSpec tests. Comparing variables that hold the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, travis-ci, rspec-rails

I have such test

```
  it 'could not update question' do
    old_title = question.title
    old_body = question.body
    old_updated_at = question.updated_at

    patch :update, id: question, question: attributes_for(:question, title: 'new valid title', body: 'new valid body'), format: :js
    question.reload

    expect(question.title).to eq old_title
    expect(question.body).to eq old_body
    expect(question.updated_at).to eq old_updated_at
  end
```

It raises an error:

> 1) QuestionsController PATCH #update question by someone else could
>   not update question
>        Failure/Error: expect(question.updated_at).to eq old_updated_at
>
> ```
>    expected: 2016-04-09 18:05:03.650576201 +0000
>         got: 2016-04-09 18:05:03.650576000 +0000
> ```

How could it be different?? On my local machine it passes

Comment: Rule of thumb: *Never trust floating point numbers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to improve the structure of your test. Consider using mocks & stubs rather than testing state mutation (or lack thereof):

```
it 'could not update question' do
    expect(Question).to_not receive(:update)  # Depending on how your model gets updated
    patch :update, id: question, question: attributes_for(:question, title: 'new valid title', body: 'new valid body'), format: :js
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers#travel](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html#method-i-travel_to)

Include it in `rails_helper.rb` like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
include ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers
...
```

And then in your tests, use `travel_to Time.now` to freeze the time.